# Using Visual Studio webtests, can you combine transaction times with the same name across different webtests?

Tags: visual-studio, performance-testing, web-testing

When running performance tests in Visual Studio, I often find that the same transaction (navigate to home, log-out, etc.) is exercised across multiple scripts. After the test is run, these transactions are broken out by their respective webtest name.

Is there a way to have VS combine these transactions by name even though multiple webtests perform that transaction? That way, I can have a timing per flow as well as an overall performance timing metric for that transaction.

Comment: As far as I know there is no "out of the box" way of doing this. All the data is available in the SQL load test database, so you could write your own SQL query. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/slumley/2010/02/12/description-of-tables-and-columns-in-vs-2010-load-test-database/ , although this is dated 2010 very little has changed in the database since the blog page was written.